# JavaScript .animate() doesn't work on Chrome 69 and up

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jquery-animate

I have a very simple JavaScript animation using .animate() that works on all versions of Chrome before 69. The rest of the JS logic works and responds but the animation simply doesn't show.

Is there a known issue with this Chrome release?

Chrome version 70 Beta also doesn't animate.

This is my JS snippet:

```
  img.setAttribute("height", "120");
  img.setAttribute("width", "250");
  var grid = document.getElementById("overlay2");
  grid.style.zIndex = 1;
  $(img).hide().appendTo(grid).animate({height: "250px", width: "250px"}, 1500, "swing");
```

Although, this does work: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_animate 
So I don't know where exactly the issue is then...

Comment: why `.hide()` ??

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/spxre9yq/) works perfectly fine on Chrome 69 for me. Given your line it looks like the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: the hide ie because i didn't want the image to be visible until i animated it. is there a better solution? it took me long to find this line!

Comment: @ChrisG, I added more lines of code in case you can see something wrong in there

Comment: It still works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/spxre9yq/ - It's probably some minor thing, so you should create a [mcve]

Comment: Turns out it’s not an issue with animation.